# How to display cardflip animation in listview?

Tags: android, listview, animation, android-fragments, android-listview

I prepared two custom view named BackView and FrontView. A custom card contains a couple of BackView and FrontView (back to back).

I want to make a listView and each listView item will be that custom card which I described above and cards will be flipping with an animation.

You can imagine that each listView item like 
[Displaying Card Flip Animations](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html)

What should I use to make this listView? Should I use fragment or not need the fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use Fragment.

You just need a custom Adapter that inflates your custom View implementing the card flip animation in every cell of the list.

Comment: But how to insert two customViews to one listView item. when the frontView pressed, it will turn and backView come to front side. I made it one customView but I cannot add second view to backside.

Comment: Your custom view can be a FrameLayout with 2 views inside: the front and the back side